# Audio played once only in Google Chrome in html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

The below code is how I put audio in my webpage. It will play the sound when I received protocol from my slave device.

```
<script>
function RxProtocol()
 {
    var a = document.getElementById("audio1");
    a.play();
 }

</script>

<body>
<audio id="audio1">
<source src="audio.wav" type="audio/wav">
<source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
audio tag not supported.
</audio>
</body>
```

It is suppose to play the sound each time it received a protocol. But when I use google Chrome, it just play once only (after refresh/reloading the page) when it received the first protocol. After that it is silence when receive protocols.

Other browser like IE9 or firefox do not have this problem. Do you guys know why?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding addEventListener :

```
<script>
function RxProtocol()
 {
    var a = document.getElementById("audio1");
    a.play();
 }

document.addEventListener("load", RxProtocol, false);

</script>
```

Regards, Daniel

Comment: May I know what is this event listener for?

Comment: With document.addEventListener("load", RxProtocol, false); the function RxProtocol is executed after the document is loaded. You use a listener in order to listen the loaded event of the document

Comment: Try deleting audio.wav and adding a format .ogg of audio ... if you don't have .ogg format , look for conversors in internet

Answer (score 0):

We need to load first for Google Chrome:

```
function RxProtocol()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("audio1");

    if (window.chrome) {
        a.load();
    }

     a.play();
 }
```